# Добавление scrollbar'a в graph view

Tags: android

Есть ли возможность в библиотеке *graphview* добавить к визуальному отображению графика `scrollbar`. Так же интересует, есть ли возможность поставить по краям `viewport` два элемента, например, стрелок, по нажатию на которые сам график будет прокручиваться.
Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: обернуть в виджет `Graphview` в `ScrollView`?

Comment: Оу, не будет ли тогда сам viewport целиком прокручиваться, вместе с осями? Я в любом случае попробую, но как бы не вышел скролл в скролле.